# Getting Slider Value on Mouse Move

Tags: silverlight

i have a silverlight screen with slider. added a Move move event for that slider.how to know what is value of slider at which mouse cursor is currently pointing. Remember i have not clicked on slider so value wont change. I want value of slider at which mouse cursor is pointing not slider's current value.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is  Bind the sliders value property to your Textblocks Text property and then you would get the value updated every time it gets changed.

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=YourSlider,Path=Value}"
```

or you can make use of

```
 Math.Round(Slider.Value, [Number of Decimals]).ToString()
```